# Sencha touch add mask format to number field

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, mask, phone-number

I create project **Sencha touch 2** lib using **Sencha Architect**.
How to add a mask format (US Phone number mask) on a only-accept-number-filed

For example, when user input

> 1234567890

, it should display

> 123-456-7890 or (123) 456-7890

When i try to use **Number Field** which can help filter only-accept-number but when I set value of Number field to 123-0001 it only show up 122 as it do minus 123 and 1.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Touch has an awesome facility which you can use to your needs. Have a look at [Class System description](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/class_system), its first part where discussed setName() usage

in short every config entry has corresponding apply() and update() function which is used through all codebase

EDIT
in your case you need to define a new class, name it PhoneText

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.field.PhoneText', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Text',
    xtype: 'phonetextfield',
    applyValue: function(value) {
        var ext = getExt(value),
            partOne = getPartOne(value),
            partTwo = getPartTwo(value);

        return Ext.String.format('(%s) %s-%s', ext, partOne, partTwo)
    }
}
```

just use your own version applyValue function which convert input value to your format.

Note that in panel definition you should use xtype: 'phonetextfield', not 'textfield', and add requires: ['MyApp.ux.field.PhoneText'] as well.

Comment: I'm not so clear about Sencha System class, can you please help me with a example. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can you use spinnerfield,It will allow character also and mask it and then set value as you doing.

Comment: it should not a Spinner field for phone number field. thank for your answer

Comment: then use textfield and mask it to allow only number,brakets and dash.

Comment: how to set textfield to allow only number,brakets and dash, is there any option like that or i have to                                     code with `onKeyUp` event